# How to mocking DbRawSqlQuery<int> result?

Tags: c#, mocking, xunit, qsqlquery

I created a method for check that in db has a stored procedure.

```
public class StoredProcedure : IStoredProcedure
{
    private readonly IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext> _dbContextProvider;

    public StoredProcedure(IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider;
    }

    public bool ExistsStoredProcedure(string procedureName)
    {   
        var query = string.Format(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [sys].[objects] WHERE [type_desc] = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' AND [name] = '{0}';",
            procedureName);
        var request = _dbContextProvider.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).Single();

        return request > 0 ? true : throw new UserFriendlyException(
            $"Хранимая процедура {procedureName} не найдена в БД {_dbContextProvider.DbContext.Database.Connection.Database}");
    }
}
```

Also, I want to write a unit test for him.

```
public class StoredProcedureTests
{
    private readonly IStoredProcedure _storedProcedure;

    private readonly Mock<IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>> _mockDbProvider;

    public StoredProcedureTests()
    {
        _mockDbProvider = new Mock<IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>>();
        _storedProcedure = new StoredProcedure(_mockDbProvider.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CheckValueIfStoredProcedureExist()
    {   
        const int count = 1;
        var rawMock = new Mock<DbRawSqlQuery<int>>();
        rawMock.Setup(i => i.Single()).Returns(count);
        _mockDbProvider.Setup(i => i.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(rawMock.Object);
        var result = _storedProcedure.ExistsStoredProcedure(string.Empty);
        Assert.True(result);
    }
}
```

But, i get an error, when i try rawMock.Setup

```
try
{
    rawMock.Setup(i => i.Single()).Returns(count);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    throw;
}
```

> Invalid setup on an extension method: i => i.Single()

How to correctly write this stub?

**UPD** I try like advised Johnny

```
try
{
    IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int> {1};
    var mq = new Mock<DbRawSqlQuery<int>>();
    mq.Setup(i => i.GetEnumerator()).Returns(list.GetEnumerator);

    _mockDbProvider.Setup(i => i.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mq.Object);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    throw;
}
```

And i have a new error

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: i => i.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery(It.IsAny(), new[] {  })

Comment: Why do you need to setup with `DbRawSqlQuery<int>` is is not really possible. The return value of `SqlQuery<int>` is `IEnumerable<int>` you could just one list...

Comment: Don't mock `DbContext`, instead write and execute test against actual database. Unit test with mocked DbContext, produce no value, because it is tightly(very tightly)  coupled to the implementation details of DbContext.

Comment: I want to test the only concrete some logic. It`s not an integration test.